# Slick.js create multiple carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, slick.js

I want to create three carousels:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#c1').slick({
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 7 * 1000,
            mobileFirst: true,
            arrows: true
        }); 
         $('#c2').slick({
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 7 * 1000,
            mobileFirst: true,
            arrows: false
        });
         $('#c3').slick({
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 7 * 1000,
            mobileFirst: true,
            arrows: false
        });
     });
```

But when i execute this code, this error message appears:

```
slick.min.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
```

I also tried this here:

```
.not('.slick-initialized').slick()
```

Then it throws no error, but only the first carousel gets created.

Do you guys have any ideas?
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like slickslider can't find an object it needs.
Make sure the your ID's (c1,c2,c3) exist in your code.

From the official slickslider-page(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/):

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you don't call the slick() function twice on the same element aswell.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I checked my variables and saw that both variables generate the same id... Now it works, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest another solution with single class or id if our settings are the same for each carousel we want to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myCarousel = $(".carousel");
myCarousel.each(function() {        
    $(this).slick({
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 7 * 1000,
        mobileFirst: true,
        arrows: false
    });
  }); 
});
```